# Tomcat process which is listed several times

Tags: logging, tomcat, htop

I have a Tomcat 9 server running on my Centos 7.

When I issue the `htop` command I have a tomcat process which is listed several times and I would like to understand why it appears several times

```
 PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
   18 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:07.27 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    1 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  1:16.08 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   20 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:01.05 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   33 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.25 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   36 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.36 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   17 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:34.36 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   38 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.86 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   21 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.08 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   42 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.70 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   58 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.22 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   13 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.95 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   35 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.39 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   40 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.31 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   34 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.85 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   37 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.37 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   24 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.09 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   10 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:21.94 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   11 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.90 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   12 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.93 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   14 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.01 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   15 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.02 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   16 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.00 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   19 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.06 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   22 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.02 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   23 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.00 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   25 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.06 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   28 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.00 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   29 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.00 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   31 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.04 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   32 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.04 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   39 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.74 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   41 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.25 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   44 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.12 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   45 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.02 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   46 root       20   0 5517M 1264M 13248 S  0.0 10.9  0:00.00 /docker-java-home/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

**/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
Wants=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el8_0.x86_64/jre

Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true'

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Enable Tomcat service to autostart on system start.**

```
systemctl enable tomcat
```

Comment: how are you starting your tomcat?

Comment: @BANJOSA I updated my post.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the content the following file in your tomcat home:  $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml (just do a locate server.xml if you're not sure where it is) and check the maxThreads and minSpareThreads settings in your file.

Basically it's mostly used in heavy load/high concurrent users - tomcat setups.
The setting is just to tell tomcat the minimum and maximum of threads it needs/can spawn to handle the http requests.

hope this answers your question

Comment: `<!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->`


These lines are commented in my file

Comment: And there are no other xml's in your $CATALINA_HOME/conf/ directory overwriting this or having other "service"-tags launching separate services? Can you check tomcat only listens on 1 port (ss -pln | grep java) should give you the output which ports java (and thus also tomcat) is using.

Comment: The default value is **10** for `minSpareThreads` and **200** for `maxThreads` per **Connector** element (cf. [Tomcat's configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation)), i.e. every **Connector** has an implicit `<Executor>` with those values. @timmeyh, there is a typo in your answer: `minThreads` instead of `minSpareThreads`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Thanks for your input, I forgot the default values since I mostly explicitly declare them :) The minSpareThreads is Aarons typo in his comment btw.

Comment: @timmeyh, `minSpareThreads` is the correct one.